# Square bracket indicating "A or B or C"

Tags: equations, brackets

How can I write `$A.B.C=0$` equivalent to `$A=0$` or `$B=0$` or `$C=0$` in this form?

I am a newbie in latex. I would like to write an expression such as the following
[image]

How can I do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8ONP.png) instead?

Comment: @Werner No, that would not convey the right idea.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? What's wrong in saying explicitly “or”?

Comment: @Werner In my country, the square bracket means "or", braces { means "and", so I cannot use braces { in this situation.

Comment: @Cathy: I'm sure the brace-police will be hot on your tail if you do use it... ;)

Comment: @Cathy Next time, please add the title also inside the question, for better clarity. You see, people unfortunately seems to skip reading the title.

Comment: I hope it's ok, I changed the title of the question so it would be more clear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a solution that allows any number of choices for the bracket:

[image]

The call for this output is `\orbrace[.5]{A=0,B=0,C=0,D=0}`

The command `\orbrace` takes 2 arguments, one optional. The optional `.5` is the spacing in cm between each option (default is 1). The required comma-separated list gives the options to be typeset in math mode.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\orbrace}[2][1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, semithick, baseline={([yshift=-.88mm]current bounding box.center)}]
    \foreach[var=\x, count=\m] in {#2}{
    \ifnum \m>1 \draw(0,-\m*#1) -- ++(0,#1); \fi
    \draw (0,-\m*#1) -- ++(.1,0) node[right] {$\x$};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\[
A.B.C.D=0 \Leftrightarrow \orbrace[.5]{A=0,B=0,C=0,D=0}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very nice! The only concern one might have is the alignment of the `=` sign in e.g. `\orbrace[.5]{4}{A=0,B_1=0,C=0,D=0}` (which is why I decided to go with `tikzmark` and `aligned`). Of course, not everyone will want to have the `=` signs aligned. (And very naively one does not need the mandatory argument, i.e. the number of options, since you only need to count the number of entries in the list.)

Comment: That's true, @Lazysquirrel. Do you know of a command that will count the elements in the list without looping through it twice? I thought about doing that but this seemed easier. Maybe just lazier.

Comment: You already count them with `count=\n`. The only problem is to "smuggle" the count of the groups that are formed with `foreach`. pgf has `\pgfutil@pushmacro` and `\pgfutil@popmacro`, which you could use (of course after wrapping your `\newcommand` into `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`), or defining a public global macro (which I think should be avoided). (As a side remark, your command works a bit "by accident" (this is not meant to be a criticism), you may want to use `\draw (0,{#2*#1-#1*(\n)})` to avoid confusing the Ti*k*Z parser.)

Comment: @SandyG I can not get the result.

Comment: I agree with @minhthien_2016 that your code does not work with the current version of pgf, i.e. v3.1.7. This is because of [this issue](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/702) and its fix, which makes `\m` local. (I should have told you when Werner made his suggestion but I was busy, sorry.) (And when one repairs it and has only three items, the baseline of the second one is off. This is not a criticism, just to report an observation.)

Comment: And of course you do not have to count. `\newcommand{\orbrace}[2][1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, semithick, baseline={([yshift=-.88mm]current bounding box.center)}]
    \foreach[var=\x, count=\n] in {#2}{
    \draw (0,-\n*#1) -- ++(.1,0) node[right] {$\x$};
 \ifnum\n>1
  \draw (0,-\n*#1) -- ++(0,#1);
 \fi
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}}`

Comment: I was unaware of this. I was using an older version. Now I see the problem in v3.1.7.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel, Ha! I came up with the same solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @minhthien_2016, thanks for pointing out the issue. I was using an older version of pgf. Fixed now.

Comment: @SandyG How can I get the result of `\[
 A.B.C.D=0 \Leftrightarrow \orbrace[.5]{\dfrac{1}{2},B=0,C=0,D=0}
 \]`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016, either increase the `.5` to create more space (`.8` looks ok to me), or use `\tfrac` to force the smaller fraction.

Answer (score 12):

Second attempt. Thanks go to Steven B. Segelets for communicating to me that the first attempt was not what the author wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[A\cdot B\cdot C=0\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad\hspace{1ex}
\begin{aligned}
\tikzmarknode{A}{A}&=0\\ \tikzmarknode{B}{B}&=0\\ \tikzmarknode{C}{C}&=0
\end{aligned}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[semithick] ([xshift=-2pt]A.west) -- ++ (-1ex,0) |- ([xshift=-2pt]C.west)
  ([xshift=-2pt]A.west|-B) -- ++ (-1ex,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On behalf of the OCD community, please make the tick at B vertically aligned with the centerline of the arrow :)

Comment: @Diaa, there's a vertical shift of about .88mm (approx .5ex). I have never understood where this comes from.

Comment: @Diaa (at)SandyG The vertical "misalignment" is a consequence of the vertical center of `B` and `\Longleftrightarrow` being different. You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myverticaladjustment}{0.33*(height("$\Longleftrightarrow$")-height("$B$"))}
 \draw[semithick] ([xshift=-2pt]A.west) -- ++ (-1ex,0) |- ([xshift=-2pt]C.west)
  ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=\myverticaladjustment*1pt]A.west|-B) -- ++ (-1ex,0);` but in general one would need to know what glyphs are used here. Possible to write a macro that takes this into account, but complicated. (I agree that this looks a bit better, though.)

Comment: @Lazysquirrel, I don't think that's the reason. I get the same effect if I leave all three items blank.

Comment: @SandyG But the vertical position of `B` is controlled by `aligned`, i.e. independent of  Ti*k*Z. All Ti*k*Z does is to attach some lines, in this case at the vertical center of the `B` node. And now there is a concern that this does not sit at the tip of the arrow. So, if one wants to change this, one has to somehow know the vertical position of the arrow tip. I do agree, though, that `\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\left\{\begin{aligned}
A&=0\\ B&=0\\ C&=0
\end{aligned}\right.` does not have the issue (at the expense of the brace closing at the top of `A` but way below the bottom of `C`).

Comment: @Diaa Done, but in a separate answer.

Comment: I think I misunderstood which `B` you were talking about. I get it now.

Answer (score 7):

I decided to put this in a second post for clarity. It is an attempt to combine the virtues of the existing answers, namely the convenience of [Sandy G's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574320) and the alignment of the baseline and the equality signs of my own. Now you can add a complete set of options, but for internal reasons and the ability to use this also in `beamer` you need to use `\&` instead of `&`. And, unlike in ordinary `aligned` environments where this is sort of optional you cannot swallow the final `\\`. Other than that you can use the `aligned` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,tikzmark}
\tikzset{aligned/.cd,h/.initial=1ex,
    lines/.code={\tikzset{aligned/linestyle/.append style={#1}}},
    linestyle/.style={line cap=round,line join=round,semithick}}
\newcommand{\AlignedTikZ}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(tmpbase.base)},
    aligned/.cd,#1]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,cells={nodes={inner xsep=.1111em}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={anchor=base east}},
    ampersand replacement=\&] (tmpmat) {#2};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mybaserow}{(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+1)/2}
\ifodd\pgfmatrixcurrentrow  
\path (tmpmat-\mybaserow-1.base) node[anchor=base] (tmpbase){};
\else
\path (tmpmat-\the\numexpr\mybaserow+1\relax-1.base) --
 node[anchor=base] (tmpbase){}
(tmpmat-\mybaserow-1.base);
\fi
\draw[aligned/linestyle] foreach \X in {1,...,\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
{(tmpmat.west|-tmpmat-\X-1) -- ++ (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aligned/h},0)}
([xshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aligned/h}]tmpmat.west|-tmpmat-1-1) --
([xshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aligned/h}]tmpmat.west|-tmpmat-\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\relax-1);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\[
A\cdot B\cdot C=0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 
\AlignedTikZ{A\&=0\\ B\&=0\\ C\&=0\\}
\]

\[
A\cdot B\cdot C=0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 
\AlignedTikZ[lines={thick,blue}]{A\&=0\\ B\&=0\\ C\&=0\\}
\]

\[
A\cdot B_1\cdot C_{12}=0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 
\AlignedTikZ{A\&=0\\ B_1\&=0\\ C_{12}\&=0\\}
\]

\[
A\cdot B_1\cdot C_{12}\cdot D=0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 
\AlignedTikZ{A\&=0\\ B_1\&=0\\ C_{12}\&=0\\ D\&=0\\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The appearance can be controlled by pgf keys. If you want to change the lengths of the horizontal bars, just add `h=1em`, say to the options. If you want to add features this can be done, too, without losing backwards compatibility.

Comment: I am happy to announce that the squirrels are now the best animal friends with the OCD community members :)

Comment: @Diaa He got tested though:p [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mr6XHJ7qcSE)